# Failed to access XML Node in multi threaded WPF Application

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, multithreading

I try to access an Attribute of an XMLNode from different threads in my WPF application. But the first access from a thread, which is not the creating thread of the XMLDocument, causes an exception of type  System.InvalidOperationException.

With detail:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

Here is my code

```
Monitor.Enter(lockAttribute); 

try 
{
    if (xmlInputNode.Attributes[sm_Attribute] != null) 
    {
        xmlInputNode.Attributes[sm_Attribute].InnerText = sm_AttributeValue.ToString();
    }
}

finally 
{
    Monitor.Exit(lockAttribute); 
}
```

I don't understand this exception. The XMLDocument is not a WPF control, that would have a DependencyObject and an associated Dispatcher.

Comment: Make a breakpoint on if(XML..). It will be probably on worker thread. And this error says, that you should use main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate
{
    if (xmlInputNode.Attributes[sm_Attribute] != null) 
    {
        xmlInputNode.Attributes[sm_Attribute].InnerText = sm_AttributeValue.ToString();
    }
}));
```